# Simple Ruby Method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that takes a string, then finds the words with at least two vowels, and adds them to another array like the following:

```
anyString = "Today we had football for breakfast"
#=> "today", "football", "breakfast"
```

If this was another language, I would do a few for loops, then add the words if the counter reached more than two. I wonder what the simplest way to do this in Ruby would be. I'm trying to get better at algorithms. Could anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"Today we had football for breakfast"
.downcase.scan(/\w*[aeiou]\w*[aeiou]\w*/)
#=> ["today", "football", "breakfast"]
```

If you want to generalize this to "at least n vowels," then replace the regex with

```
/(?:\w*[aeiou]){n}\w*/
```

Comment: would you mind explaining this a little bit? I don't understand how the "/" work.

Comment: @Jadex1 `/ /` is for Regular expression, and whatever is written between `/` and `/` is expression written to parse the string which matches the exact expression.

Comment: @sawa better use `[aeiouAEIOU]` than downcase or you capture the downcased version. Doesn't matter much in english, but e.g. in german it would be fatal. And it's also faster^^

Comment: @ascar The OP wanted a downcased result. The OP doesn't have German examples.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`String#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-count) method for this.

```
str = "Today we had football for breakfast"
str.downcase.split.select { |s| s.count("aeiou") > 1 }
# => ["today", "football", "breakfast"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking in imperative languages like C. This would be a more Rubyesque way:

```
anyString.downcase.split.select {|word| word.scan(/[aeiou]/).size >= 2 }
```

Comment: He wants words with at least two vowels, not just 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Today we had football for breakfast"

str.downcase.split.select { |w| w.gsub(/[^aeiou]/,'').size > 1 }
  #=> ["today", "football", "breakfast"]
```

I used `downcase` rather than `(/[^aeiou]/i` because the example given in the question (`"Today"`) suggests that downcased words are to be collected.

Answer (score 0):

Other variant

```
anyString.downcase.split(' ').select { |word| word.match(/.*[aeiou].*[aeiuo].*/) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
any_string.split.select { |w| w.scan(/[aeiou]/i).size > 1 }
=> ["Today", "football", "breakfast"]
```